# How to construct a sobel filter for kernel initialization in input layer for images of size 128x128x3?

Tags: tf.keras, conv-neural-network, sobel

This is my code for sobel filter:

```
def init_f(shape, dtype=None):

    sobel_x = tf.constant([[-5, -4, 0, 4, 5], [-8, -10, 0, 10, 8], [-10, -20, 0, 20, 10], [-8, -10, 0, 10, 8], [-5, -4, 0, 4, 5]])

    ker = np.zeros(shape, dtype)
    ker_shape = tf.shape(ker)
    kernel = tf.tile(sobel_x, ker_shape)//*Is this correct?*
    return kernel

model.add(Conv2D(filters=30, kernel_size=(5,5), kernel_initializer=init_f, strides=(1,1), activation='relu'))
```

So far I have managed to do this.
But, this gives me error:

```
Shape must be rank 2 but is rank 4 for 'conv2d_17/Tile' (op: 'Tile') with input shapes: [5,5], [4].
```

Tensorflow Version: 2.1.0

Comment: Please include your tensorflow version so people can look up the api easier.  Why would you use the tf.tile though? From the docs, its for creating a bunch of repeated elements. You've already created a 5x5 kernel, what do you need to repeate?

Comment: Your Conv2D has 30 filters, it seems like you only want 1 filter?

Comment: I referred the answer by vijay m on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50913430/13368020

Comment: How should I do it for 30 filters then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're close, but the args to tile don't appear to be correct. That is why you're getting the error "Shape must be rank 2 but is rank 4 for..." You're sobel_x must be a rank 4 tensor, so you need to add two more dimensions. I used reshape in this example.

```
from tensorflow import keras
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy

def kernelInitializer(shape, dtype=None):
    print(shape)    
    sobel_x = tf.constant(
        [
            [-5, -4, 0, 4, 5], 
            [-8, -10, 0, 10, 8], 
            [-10, -20, 0, 20, 10], 
            [-8, -10, 0, 10, 8], 
            [-5, -4, 0, 4, 5]
        ], dtype=dtype )
    #create the missing dims.
    sobel_x = tf.reshape(sobel_x, (5, 5, 1, 1))

    print(tf.shape(sobel_x))
    #tile the last 2 axis to get the expected dims.
    sobel_x = tf.tile(sobel_x, (1, 1, shape[-2],shape[-1]))

    print(tf.shape(sobel_x))
    return sobel_x

x1 = keras.layers.Input((128, 128, 3))

cvl = keras.layers.Conv2D(30, kernel_size=(5,5), kernel_initializer=kernelInitializer, strides=(2,2), activation='relu')

model = keras.Sequential();
model.add(x1)
model.add(cvl)

data = numpy.ones((1, 128, 128, 3))
data[:, 0:64, 0:64, :] = 0

pd = model.predict(data)
print(pd.shape)

d = pd[0, :, :, 0]
for row in d:
    for col in row:
        m = '0'
        if col != 0:
            m = 'X'
        print(m, end="")
    print("")
```

I looked at using `expand_dims` instead of reshape but there didn't appear any advantage. `broadcast_to` seems ideal, but you still have to add the dimensions, so I don't think it was better than tile.

Why 30 filters of the same filter though? Are they going to be changed afterwards?

Comment: I tried modifying the code based on your answer. It now shows this error. Tensor-typed variable initializers must either be wrapped in an init_scope or callable (e.g., `tf.Variable(lambda : tf.truncated_normal([10, 40]))`) when building functions.

Comment: This current layer is only used to pass the image through a high pass filter. The actual task is to classify an image as authentic or forged which will be done in the subsequent layers. I am implementing this research paper  https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7823911

Comment: @drum_stick Which line is that? I tested it on tf 1.13 and figured it would be fine because the api's are the same for the functions being used. I can update it for tf 2.1.

Comment: The line where Conv2D layer is defined. model.add(Conv2D(filters=30, kernel_size=(5,5), kernel_initializer=kernelInitializer, strides=(2,2), activation='relu'))

Comment: Considering your line says. `model.add(Conv2D(filters=30, kernel_size=(5,5), kernel_initializer=kernelInitializer, strides=(2,2), activation='relu')) ` You're definitely not using the exact code. Can you try reducing it down to just the creation of a Conv2D layer? Do you see the print statements?

Comment: I changed the code to just creating the Conv2D layer. Still it showed the same layer.

Comment: Then I modified to this: cv = keras.layers.Conv2D(
       30, kernel_size=(5,5), 
       kernel_initializer= lambda: kernelInitializer
     )(x1) The new error is this: <lambda>() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dtype'

Comment: Yes, the print outputs are there.

Comment: I don't think that is where the lambda needs to go, I also don't think it needs to be a python lambda, but a tensorflow lambda. Also, I installed tf2.1 and this code works fine without an error for me.

Comment: My code still doesn't work. But I guess it's some other error now. Anyways, you have solved my original question. Thank you so much!

Comment: Best of luck, I've updated the example to include the imports and making a prediction just in case it is something like using keras instead of tensorflow.keras.

Comment: Lol! The error was actually keras instead of tensorflow.keras. Thanks a lot again!